# get customer id in payment method block for new order in admin

Tags: php, magento

How could I get the `customer Id` selected in magento admin for `new order` in my `payment method block`

[image: new order - magento admin]

My payment method block extends to `Mage_Payment_Block_Form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a single line of code and caused me to wait for hours.

> Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getCustomerId();